# Choppy height CSSTransition in react with multiple items

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, lag

***Goal*:** I'm getting really frustrated and have been scavenging through posts for hours now and can't find any real solution. I'm trying to animation a table row's height to expand/collapse when clicked on. I figured there should be an easy enough solution... Boy was I wrong.

Ideally since each row is going to store quite a bit of extra data, I'd like to load in the data, expand that single row, then remove the data when it's collapsed.

***Problem*:**
I managed to get the animation working great!! I was so excited, only to find out that when I have more than ~3 rows, it gets extremely choppy/laggy. I can't find any fix what so ever.

Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0ql5vp13qv or if you wanted to see the code that manages the animation my code now:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import Icon2 from '../Icon';

import * as Styled from './styles'

export default class CourseRow extends Component {
  state = {switched: false};

  selectCourse = () => {
    this.setState(({switched}) => ({switched: !switched}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
         <Styled.Row onClick={this.selectCourse}>
            <Styled.InnerRow>
                <Styled.Field light>CSCI 1000</Styled.Field>
                <Styled.Field>Computer Science 1</Styled.Field>
                <Styled.Field>Explore algorithms and data structures that...</Styled.Field>
                <Styled.Field><Styled.DropdownButton ><Icon2 icon="up_arrow"/></Styled.DropdownButton></Styled.Field>
            </Styled.InnerRow>
            <CSSTransition
            classNames="fade"
            timeout={300}
            key={this.props.Title}
            in={this.state.switched}
            unmountOnExit
            >
                <div>
                    test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
        </Styled.Row>
  );
  }
}
```

```css
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from 'components/Button';

const columns = "1.5fr 2.5fr 5fr 3fr";

export const DropdownButton = styled(Button)`
    
    background-color: blue;
`;


export const InnerRow = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: ${columns};
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    grid-row-gap: 0;
    padding-top: ${props => props.heading ? '2.25rem' : '1.5rem'};
    padding-bottom: ${props => props.heading ? '2rem' : '1.5rem'};
    padding-left: 0.75rem;
    padding-right: 0.75rem;
    border-top: ${props => props.heading ? 'none' : '1px solid #E8E8E8'};
    cursor: ${props => props.heading ? 'default' : 'pointer'};
`;

export const Row = styled.div`
    &:hover {
        background-color: #f7faff;
        color: #1873EA;
    }

    & .fade-enter {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      max-height: 0;
    }
    
    & .fade-enter-active {
      max-height: 200px;
      transition: all 200ms ease;
    }
    & .fade-exit {
      max-height: 200px;
    }
    & .fade-exit-active {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      transition: all 200ms ease;
    }
`;

export const Field = styled.span`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: ${props => props.light ? '400' : '300'};
    &:last-of-type {
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
`;
```

I thought maybe adding key's to the elements/transitions would help however still nothing...

I took videos of the comparisons so you can see what I'm talking about it.

**This is with 1 row:** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6Db7nuqlgk&feature=youtu.be

**This is with ~6 rows:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Troba8eIqKA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: can you make a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io

Comment: For sure, here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/0ql5vp13qv @DanielLizik

Comment: Rather than dynamically creating the element and loading it in on the fly add a placeholder element. You trigger your animation load your data, populate the element, and animate it in. When working with with large tables of data this is my go-to solution with Vue. I was unable to reproduce the choppy animation in your sandbox. (Macbook Pro 2017 Chrome 69)